# Grok works in the debugger, but does not work in logstash.conf

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm trying to extract two fields from my unstructured logs logstash. My log messages look like this:

```
[2/9/2022 7:32:16 PM] logmessage
```

I have this Grok:

```
grok {
   match => { "message" => "\[(?<app_log_date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} (1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[1-9][0-9] (AM|PM))\] %{GREEDYDATA:app_message}" }
}
```

When I put this in the Grok debugger, it works perfectly fine, but when I put this in my logstash.conf, it produces malformed messages in my ElasticSearch output and a `_grokparsefailure`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Do I need to escape the brackets?

[image]

Comment: You're not using the same pattern in the grok debugger and your Logstash grok configuration. `\[` and `\]` are not at the same location, but it's probably not the issue

Comment: @Val right, I have tried putting them inside the ?<app_log_date> custom tag, and outside of it. Made no difference.

Comment: @VinShahrdar, Have you considered using [dissect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/plugins-filters-dissect.html) ? They are a few advantages such as speed, and readability.

Comment: The dissect expression would be `[%{app_log_date}] %{app_message}`.

Comment: @Paulo Thanks. Will check it out. This is working fine for me now!

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my logs in the morning and looks like they are getting parsed correctly! Not sure if it was my test logs that I was forcing via VS Code or what, but it is working as indented now.